# Limit Apache log on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

Yesterday I found that my Apache log file in my development machine was almost 50 GB in size.

Is there a way to limit the site of the Apache log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically done using [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html).  Example logrotate configuration for Apache:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    daily
    rotate 30
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
      /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/httpd.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: Mac OS 10.5 and up use newsyslog and the config file is located in /etc/newsyslog.conf. a man newsyslog and man newsyslog.conf should helped a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard (10.6.8),
  following Onema's comment (on [an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/187814/limit-apache-log-mac-os-10-6/187816#187816)),
  I added this line to /etc/newsyslog.conf(5) (with reformatted whitespace):

```
# logfilename                   [owner:group]   mode    count   size    when    flags   [/pid_file]         [sig_num]
/var/log/apache2/*_log          70:70           644     5       1000    *       JG      /var/run/httpd.pid
```

It instructs to rotate all logs (3 for me) 5 times each when over 1000 "kilobytes", using bzip2(1)

Comment: Note that the [owner:group], [/pid-file], and [sig_num] fields are optional and hence can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Warner's suggestion, here's a logrotate config to delete your Apache logs if they grow larger than 5MB:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    size=5M
    daily
}
```